# некорректная работа fscanf

Tags: c, файлы, функции, scanf

Вопрос таков:
имеется файл с матрицой, допустим

1. 1    0   0
2. 0    0   0
3. 0    2   3
4. 0    0   0

я осуществляю обход значений по столбцам, обход работает правильно, это проверено.
( если что, сначала читается первый столбец, то есть 1 0 0 0, потом второй 0 0 2 0 и т.д.)
проблема в том, что fscanf работает крайне странно
по идее, после 2-ки  следующий элемент во втором столбце при моей схеме обхода - это 0. и алгоритм действительно переходит на элемент  ниже, только fscanf почему то видит там не 0, а 3-ку.
с чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

```
FILE* gt = fopen(filename, "r");
int ger1=0;
int ker1=0;
(fscanf(gt,"%dx%d", &ger1, &ker1));
cols = ker1;
rows=ger1;
max_size=rows*cols;
for ( re =1; re <= cols; re++)
{
    rem=1;
    for (rem=re;rem<=max_size;rem=rem+cols) {
      
    fscanf(gt,"%lf", &cm);

    
        if (cm !=0 )
       {
         ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть код показали, а то гадаем на кофейной гуще.... Воспользуйтесь советами [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: я добавил, но я просто не думаю, что он сильно поможет

Comment: Допустим, циклы вы написали так, что обход осуществляется по столбцам. Но какая связь между индексами циклов и функцией `fscanf`? Она как читала файл построчно, так и продолжает читать. Зачем вы пытаетесь обрабатывать _файл_ по столбцам? Уточните задачу. Если размер матрицы мал, то проще считать её целиком в память, и только потом обходить её любым удобным способом.

Comment: @wololo ага, то есть проблема в том, что fscanf продолжает читать построчно и ему в общем и целом "наплевать" на мои индексы? 
я просто думал, что он сможет считывать не построчно, а отдельным "полям" что лежат под индексами.

Comment: @wololo я выше написал, я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Да, `fscanf` читает данные в файле подряд, как они расположены. Считал первое число, потом второе, и т.д. Он ничего не знает о количестве строк, столбцов.